# A basic ODE question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $G \subset \Bbb R^d$ be open and let $ V: G \to [0, \infty)$ be such that $\dot{V} = \nabla V.h : G \to \Bbb R$is non-positive. We assume that $H=\{x: V(x) =0\}$ is equal to the set $\{x: \dot{V}(x) =0\}$ and is a compact subset of $G$. Let there be an open set $B$ with compact closure such that $H \subset B \subset{\bar{B}} \subset G$. Then there are two claims :

From Lasalle invariance principle we can say that any internally chain transitive invariant subset of $\bar{B}$ will be subsets of $H$. Is any internally chain transitive invariant set a subset of an omega-limit set? I don't think so.

Comment: @Winther: I want soln/hint.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you, it's a bit too advanced for me, but hopefully someone here can. If not then you could try [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/).

Comment: @Winther: I got it. The solution requires much more advanced concept like asymptotic pseudo-trajectory.

Comment: If $V=V(x(t))$ then $\dot{V}=\nabla V \cdot \dot{x}$.